# Creating list of list based on index and value

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have been given a list of  positive integer numbers upto 10^6 and total number of item in the given list will be 10** 4 at most. I want to store these values in a particular order as explained below.

I want to iterate through the list and want to place the index value of item in the inner list corresponding to that item.

## Example

Given List : `[3,0,1,1]`

output : `[[1],[2,3],[],[0]]` #expected output

basically output list should contains lists with index corresponding to item value in given list which should contain index value

I have comeup with this solution.

```
sequence = [[]] * 4
given = [3,0,1,1]
index = 0
for num in given:
    sequence[num].append(index)
    index+=1
print(sequence)
```

but the output I am getting is `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]` and cannot figure out why.

Comment: `sequence = [[]] * 4` will create 4 of the same list so changing one will change the others. try changing it to `sequence = [[] for _ in range(4)]`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Got it, I was trying debugging for hours.

Comment: @LeoE it does. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
a = [3, 0, 1, 1]
[[j for j, k in enumerate(a) if k == i] for i, _ in enumerate(a)]
#[[1], [2, 3], [], [0]]
```